# TypeError: can't pickle MplCanvas objects

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror, dump, dill

I'm trying to save a rather complex object as a file that looks something like

```
import methods
import vars
import matplotlib
import numpy

class Awesome:
    def __init__(self, canvasHandle, x, y):
        self.alpha = 'jada'
        self.bravo = 'bla'
        self.graphic, = canvasHandle.ax.plot(x,y,'r-')
        ... 
    def show(self):
        self.graphic.set_visible(True)
    def hide(self):
        self.graphic.set_visible(False)
```

However, when i run **dill** with

```
with open('awesome.job', 'wb') as outputFile:
    dill.dump(self.awesome), outputFile)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle MplCanvas objects
```

How can I save that object to a file no matter what is inside? Readability is unimportant, it just has to dump the memory and bring it back to life...

Comment: Your object should store the figure (what you call `canvasHandle` here). E.g. `self.fig = fig` in the init method.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
Instead of passing a canvas object (I did that to catch events with "mpl_connect"), I am now only passing the contained figure object. Catching the events with "mpl_connect" also works on the figure-canvas, not only the higher-level canvas (therefore no need to pass it). Now dill saves the object with no error!